# How to single sign out on Spring mvc application enabled SSO using Spring OAuth2?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, single-sign-on, spring-oauth2

I'm developing a spring web app with SSO architect by using Spring OAuth2

- 2 spring mvc web apps
- 1 authorization server is responsible for SSO and issue/check tokens
- 1 resources server serving /api/me

Everything works well when single signing on, but I don't know how to Single Sign Out (1 app logs out, other apps log out as well). Currently, it seems that every apps with mimimum config like code snippet below is using different session storage, and after successful authentication, it saves the authenticated session in its own session storage, and every subsequent requests is intercepted with the session in cookie. So when sso-server logging out it cannot invalidate related sessions on others app session storages. Anyone could suggest me some strategies for Single Sign Out?

Web client application.yml file:

```
security:
  oauth2:
    client:
      clientId: metlife_monitor
      clientSecret: password
      accessTokenUri: http://localhost:8668/sso-server/oauth/token
      userAuthorizationUri: http://localhost:8668/sso-server/oauth/authorize
      tokenName: oauth_token
    resource:
      userInfoUri: http://localhost:8688/api/me
```

Web Application class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableOAuth2Sso
@EnableJdbcHttpSession
public class Application  extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .antMatcher("/**")
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/login**", "/error**", "/webjars/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().logout()
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("http://localhost:8668/sso-server/logout")
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .deleteCookies("client-session", "JSESSIONID")
                .permitAll()
                .and().csrf().disable()
        ;

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App1Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's difference between a Single-Sign-On(SSO) server and a Central-Authentication-Server(CAS). If the your auth server does not manage any sessions, it stops being an SSO server and just becomes a CAS.

In your case you can have your SSO server manage sessions and it can also distribute a session id that Resource Servers would verify with it before servicing the request. It does lead to a chatty system though. If you can live with a little latency post session-expiry, then you can make very short-lived tokens that are attached to the SSO and would not have to verify the token with every request, you'd only refresh a token is there's still a valid session.

If you can, consider using [Keycloak](https://www.keycloak.org/documentation.html). It has adapters for Java and Javascript applications as well